# understanding String^ in C++ .Net

Tags: .net, c++, string, reference, managed-c++

I remember seeing somewhere there "^" operator is used as a pointer operator in Managed C++ code. Hence "^" should be equivalent to "*" operator right??

Assuming my understanding is right, when I started understanding .Net and coded a few example programs, I came across some code like this:

```
String ^username; //my understanding is you are creating a pointer to string obj
.
.         // there is no malloc or new that allocates memory to username pointer
.
username = "XYZ"; // shouldn't you be doing a malloc first??? isn't it null pointer
```

I am having trouble understanding this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String^` is a pointer to the managed heap, aka *handle*. Pointers and handles are not interchangable.

Calling `new` will allocate an object on an unmanaged heap and return a pointer. On the other hand, calling `gcnew` will allocate an object on a managed heap and return a handle.

The line `username = "XYZ"` is merely a compiler sugar. It is equivalent to

```
username = gcnew String(L"XYZ");
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a reference, not pointer, to a garbage collected string.

It will be allocated and deallocated automatically, when nothing is referencing it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider that `^` is similar to `shared_ptr` you will be not far from the truth.